# vim mapping key does not work

Tags: vim

I have been trying to map ctrl s to save during insert mode in vim. It never seem to work

http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Map_Ctrl-S_to_save_current_or_new_files (and many other tutorials) does not seem to work

I am using iterm, vim 7, and I have .vimrc file under my current user. I have reloaded my .vimrc with :source $MYVIMRC

Did I do something wrong?

Same thing with mapping any other key. mapping just does not seem to work.

Comment: Provide the lines from .vimrc you used for mapping.

Comment: Are you using terminal or GUI version of vim? And on which system?

Comment: The tip you linked to provides several ways to do it. Which ones did you try?

Comment: I am using terminal, iterm exactly, on mac os. (GUI version works for me). I am sorry I dont have the lines I used for mapping right now. I kept trial and error. Would be nice if you guys can provide mapping definition that works?

Answer (score 7):

Many keys cannot be intercepted on terminal, because they are interpreted by the terminal and not passed to vim at all. Ctrl-S is one of those keys, meaning "suspend" to most terminals. Either use the GUI version of vim, or select key combinations that work on your terminal.

Comment: The "Key Notation" section [here](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Mapping_keys_in_Vim_-_Tutorial_\(Part_2\)) has some notes on the flow control characters.

Comment: I have `alias vim="stty stop '' -ixoff ; vim"` which disables capturing `<C-s>` by terminal.

Comment: so have alias vim="stty stop '' -ixoff ; vim" in bash_profile and map key in .vimrc would work? would you please show me your .vimrc file? Thanks for the link I will check that out.

Comment: @limaoit 1. Don't forget about @ZyX at the start of the reply: I did not get notified and saw your comment only by accident. 2. You should not use this in bash: it disables `<C-s>` completely. In zsh due to `ttyctl -f` that is in my `~/.zshrc` it is not an issue. Review wikia link you posted here: I updated the solution with both bash and zsh versions. My vimrc is [here](http://paste.pocoo.org/show/497754/) but I bet you would have problems trying to find something useful here; the only mapping with `<C-s>` is `<C-a><C-s>` added because it is also used to switch panes in my tmux configuration.

Comment: @ZyX thanks for your answer. I am using Bash. And wow your vimrc sure has a lot of things going on

Comment: See the following for further dicussion on this: http://vim.1045645.n5.nabble.com/Disabling-terminal-flow-control-in-Vim-td1169027.html