# Why doesn't "map! <C-q> :q <CR> " work in vim?

Tags: vim

I input `:map! <C-q> :q <CR>` in command line mode, then return to normal mode, and press ctrl-q, but vim does not quit. Why?

Comment: [Jan Hudec describes that `^S` can't be mapped](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7865123/vim-mapping-key-does-not-work/7865307#7865307) -- perhaps `^Q` fails for the same reason? At least for me, `^S` and `^Q` still function for XON and XOFF.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/791765/unable-to-forward-search-bash-history-similarly-as-with-ctrl-r

Comment: Maybe the answer on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7652590/is-it-possible-to-map-c-to-in-vim/7653633#7653633 can be applied to your problem.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Why anyone would want to add yet another way of quitting Vim to the [plethora already available](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/editing.html#write-quit) is beyond me. However...

On Fedora 15, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Q</kbd> is likely being captured by your terminal as [XON](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XON) ([resume](http://catb.org/jargon/html/C/control-Q.html)) and therefore not reaching Vim to quit the application.

You can check if there's an error in your mapping or a clash like so:

```
:verbose map! <C-Q>
```

[`:map!`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/map.html#mapmode-ic) is for specifing mappings in [`insert`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/insert.html#Insert-mode) and [`command-line`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/cmdline.html#Command-line) modes.

[`normal-mode`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/intro.html#Normal) [mappings](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/map.html#:nmap) are (usually) specified like so:

```
:nmap <C-Q> :q<CR>
```

Comment: I am using Fedora 15.
But :map! <C-1> :q <CR> also not work, and I have tried many other  key combination.

Comment: @Downvoter: can you please point out what's wrong or missing from this answer?

Comment: `:nmap` will work in vanilla `vim`, too. The control character isn't getting to the application in terminal mode for the reason I outlined. [bitmask's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7884226/78845) details how you can solve this.

Comment: Ctrl+q can be done one-handed (2 keys pressed). :q enter requires two hands (4 keys pressed( shift+; q enter )). One might conclude that ctrl+q takes around half the time as :q enter, this makes it more efficient.

Comment: @zeros-ones:  `ZZ` is my preferred exit strategy.

Comment: @Johnysweb Is that a custom solution? Seems like I have heard of that before.

Comment: @zeros-ones: It's standard and documented here: http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/editing.html#ZZ

Comment: Thanks for the link @Johnysweb

Answer (score 16):

As Johnsyweb suggested, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Q</kbd> does not reach Vim in the first place. This holds for the popular <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>S</kbd> as well. Both can be fixed by adding

```
silent !stty -ixon > /dev/null 2>/dev/null
```

to your `.vimrc` as it forces these control sequences to reach the application.

Comment: I tested it. It works on my machine. What shell and what terminal emulator (if any) are you using?

Comment: @river - try putting `stty -ixon` in your .bashrc instead. Launch a new terminal, then vim.

Comment: @Ixs tested stty -ixon with putty connected to a putty-256color terminal and worked fine - thanks