# How to colorize diff on the command line

Tags: unix, command-line, colors, diff

When I have a diff, how can I colorize it so that it looks good?

I want it for the command line, so please no GUI solutions.

Comment: Any particular operating system/shell?

Comment: Try https://github.com/walles/riff. As an added bonus, it highlights what parts of the lines that changed.

Comment: emacs does great color diffs in a terminal; is that what you mean by non-GUI?  See https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/613399/80268 .

Answer (score 700, accepted):

Man pages for `diff` suggest no solution for colorization from within itself. Please consider using `colordiff`. It's a wrapper around `diff` that produces the same output as diff, except that it augments the output using colored syntax highlighting to increase readability:

```
diff old new | colordiff
```

or just:

```
colordiff old new
```

---

Installation:

- Ubuntu/Debian: `sudo apt-get install colordiff`
- OS X: `brew install colordiff` or `port install colordiff`

Comment: Just found that myself :-). It can be piped into less by using `less -R`, which displays the escape sequences for colors correctly.

Comment: Can just use the syntax: colordiff file1 file2

Comment: Alas, it doesn't work for the side-by-side output *(`-y` option to enable)* ☹ The `vimdiff` suggestion below probably a better way

Comment: on centos I needed repository rpm -Uvh  epel-release-5-4.noarch.rpm then I could yum install colordiff

Comment: `colordiff` works well for `svn diff | colordiff` (i.e. in situations where you only have the diff, not the two files being diffed).

Comment: you can just use it instead of diff, just  colordiff -y old new.

Comment: As an update to @Hi-Angel 's comment: colordiff has been updated and now includes side by side (`-y`) support.

Comment: I used this to quickly get color when using git over ssh: git diff | colordiff

Comment: @BaileyParker I am using 1.0.19 which seems to be the latest version. Using `-y` does not have any colorization.

Answer (score 388):

Use [Vim](http://www.vim.org/):

```
diff /path/to/a /path/to/b | vim -R -
```

Or better still, [VimDiff](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/diff.html#vimdiff) (or `vim -d`, which is shorter to type) will show differences between two, three or four files side-by-side.

#### Examples:

```
vim -d /path/to/[ab]
```

---

```
vimdiff file1 file2 file3 file4
```

Comment: function ddiff(){

diff $1 $2 | vim -R -

}

export -f ddiff

Comment: @Jichao: I prefer to learn the commands rather than alias them away. That way I can use them anywhere, even when my dotfiles aren't available.

Comment: vim -d has the advantage of remembering the last open position, if correct vimrc setting is used. (Such as [here](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Restore_cursor_to_file_position_in_previous_editing_session).)

Comment: looks good! I just dont understand why they dont allow ctrl+c or ctrl+q or ctrl+x on vim to exit; I always have to look on internet to quit it hehe..

Comment: @AquariusPower: [`ctrl-c`](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5030164/78845) and [`ctrl-x`](http://stackoverflow.com/q/13327285/78845) have other uses in Vim. [`ctrl-q`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7883860/78845) is captured by many terminals. See [Writing and quitting](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/editing.html#write-quit) to find the way that best suits your needs.

Comment: `vimdiff` won't handle directory `diff`s. Alternatively, you can save diff to a file, and open it with `vim`. That way you will have `vim` colorize it using built-in syntax highlighting facilities.

Comment: @x-yuri. Yes... you could use your shell to do this too, `vim -d =(ls -l ~/src/m) =(ls -l ~/src/n)`

Comment: First, what kind of shell is this? `zsh`? I don't recognize `=(...)` construct. Second, I had `diff -ur a b` in mind.

Comment: Indeed. In Zsh, a [command of the form `=(...)` is replaced with the name of a _file_ containing its output.](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Intro/intro_7.html)

Comment: `diff -ur ~/src/{m,n} | vim -` is a nice alternative. Thanks.

Comment: @Johnsyweb and @x-yuri - in Bash it's `<(...)` instead.

Comment: @BrianMcCutchon The `<(...)` form is present in zsh as well.

Comment: Actually for me it's shortest to type `vimd` + `tab` (autocomplete).

Comment: This solution is better than the accepted answer, as it does not require you to have system administrator rights and install any additional tool

Comment: Adding a note that `-R` is vim's readonly mode so you can also use the equivalent `view` command which is just vim's readonly command, i.e., `diff file1 file 2 | view -`. Adding it here for those that may prefer one over the other. Cool solution, OP!

Answer (score 204):

Actually there seems to be yet another option (which I only noticed recently, when running into the problem described above):

```
git diff --no-index <file1> <file2>
# output to console instead of opening a pager
git --no-pager diff --no-index <file1> <file2>
```

If you have Git around (which you already might be using anyway), then you will be able to use it for comparison, even if the files themselves are not under version control. If not enabled for you by default, then enabling color support here seems to be considerably easier than some of the previously mentioned workarounds.

Comment: This is neat, but sadly this doesn't work when the inputs are pipes. For example comparing binary files via `git diff <(xxd file1) <(xxd filed)` doesn't work.

Comment: Oddly, at least one of the files has to be 'outside the current repository', according to `git help diff`. So if your git diff is coming up empty, try `cd` out of where you are.

Comment: To enable colors for git diff: `git config color.diff auto`

Comment: super simple and quick

Comment: If both files are inside the current repository, use `git diff --no-index` to compare two files.

Comment: This is excellent! Compared to regular `diff`, I much prefer the way `git diff` handles files that are only in one side of a recursive diff, but I hadn't realized I could use it outside of a Git repository. Thank you!

Comment: If you want a nicer colored `git diff` I would take a look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3231759/how-can-i-visualize-per-character-differences-in-a-unified-diff-file/25634420#25634420).

Comment: I'm a fan of `git diff --word-diff --patience`

Comment: The other advantage of `git diff` is the `---` and `+++` at the top clarifying the direction of the changes.

Comment: To enable color one just one run, `git diff --color <file1> <file2>`

Comment: `~/.bashrc` += `alias cdiff='git diff --no-index'`

Comment: Great workaround if `diff --color` and `colordiff` are not available at a site!

Answer (score 155):

**`diff --color` option (added to GNU diffutils 3.4 in 2016-08-08)**

This is the default `diff` implementation on most distributions, which will soon be getting it.

[Ubuntu 18.04](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_version_history#Ubuntu_18.04_LTS_.28Bionic_Beaver.29) (Bionic Beaver) has `diffutils` 3.6 and therefore has it.

On 3.5 it looks like this:

[image]

Tested with:

```
diff --color -u \
  <(seq 6 | sed 's/$/ a/') \
  <(seq 8 | grep -Ev '^(2|3)$' | sed 's/$/ a/')
```

Apparently added in commit c0fa19fe92da71404f809aafb5f51cfd99b1bee2 (Mar 2015).

**Word-level diff**

Like `diff-highlight`. It is not possible it seems, but there is a feature request: https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/diffutils-devel/2017-01/msg00001.html

Related questions:

- *[Using 'diff' (or anything else) to get character-level diff between text files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1721738/using-diff-or-anything-else-to-get-character-level-diff-between-text-files)*
- *https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/11128/diff-within-a-line*
- *https://superuser.com/questions/496415/using-diff-on-a-long-one-line-file*

`ydiff` does it though. See below.

**`ydiff` side-by-side word level diff**

https://github.com/ymattw/ydiff

Is this nirvana?

```
python3 -m pip install --user ydiff
diff -u a b | ydiff -s
```

Outcome:

[image]

If the lines are too narrow (default 80 columns), fit to the screen with:

```
diff -u a b | ydiff -w 0 -s
```

Contents of the test files:

a

```
1
2
3
4
5 the original line the original line the original line the original line
6
7
8
9
10
11
12
13
14
15 the original line the original line the original line the original line
16
17
18
19
20
```

b

```
1
2
3
4
5 the original line the original line the original line the original line
6
7
8
9
10
11
12
13
14
15 the original line the original line the original line the original line
16
17
18
19
20
```

**`ydiff` Git integration**

`ydiff` integrates with Git without any configuration required.

From inside a Git repository, instead of `git diff`, you can do just:

```
ydiff -s
```

and instead of `git log`:

```
ydiff -ls
```

See also: *[How can I get a side-by-side diff when I do "git diff"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7669963/how-can-i-get-a-side-by-side-diff-when-i-do-git-diff/14649328#14649328)*

Tested on [Ubuntu 16.04](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_version_history#Ubuntu_16.04_LTS_.28Xenial_Xerus.29) (Xenial Xerus), Git 2.18.0, and ydiff 1.1.

Comment: [Here](https://www.gnu.org/software/diffutils/manual/diffutils.html#index-color_002c-distinguishing-different-context) is the documentation.

Comment: In that mailing list thread: `There is no word-highlighting, yet` - any updates? This is what I came to this question for (I want `grep --color`-like  diff output).

Comment: @i336_ no updates unfortunately, if I get any, I will update the question. Ping me if you find anything.

Comment: By the way `git diff --color` works too. Useful when working over ssh.

Comment: Diff too large? use `diff --color=always | less -R`

Answer (score 79):

And for those occasions when a `yum install colordiff` or an `apt-get install colordiff` is not an option due to some insane constraint beyond your immediate control, **or you're just feeling crazy**, you can reinvent the wheel with a line of sed:

```
sed 's/^-/\x1b[41m-/;s/^+/\x1b[42m+/;s/^@/\x1b[34m@/;s/$/\x1b[0m/'
```

Throw that in a shell script and pipe **unified diff** output through it.

It makes hunk markers blue and highlights new/old filenames and added/removed lines in green and red background, respectively.<sup>1</sup>  And it will make trailing space<sup>2</sup> changes more readily apparent than colordiff can.

---

<sup>1</sup> Incidentally, the reason for highlighting the filenames the same as the modified lines is that to correctly differentiate between the filenames and the modified lines requires properly parsing the diff format, which is not something to tackle with a regex.  Highlighting them the same works "well enough" visually and makes the problem trivial.  That said, there are [some interesting subtleties](https://retracile.net/blog/2013/06/01/22.00).

<sup>2</sup> But not trailing tabs.  Apparently tabs don't get their background set, at least in my [xterm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xterm).  It does make tab vs. space changes stand out a bit though.

Comment: @Matt: Here's a brute-force approach for a Mac:  `sed "s/^-/\`echo -e \"\x1b\"\`[41m-/;s/^+/\`echo -e \"\x1b\"\`[42m+/;s/^@/\`echo -e \"\x1b\"\`[34m@/;s/$/\`echo -e \"\x1b\"\`[0m/"` (though I expect there is a better way).

Comment: Hmm, it sort of worked... gave the 3 dashes between each chunk a pink background.

Comment: Manual unreadable, unmaintainable way without an option to easily change the colors for example.

Comment: @Svetlana  I think you're taking this a bit too seriously... :)

Comment: Dude this is awesome! Way to go! That is some nice sed wizardry.

Comment: aliased this awesomeness as colorize-diff-u.  Thanks.

Comment: sed 's/^-/\x1b[31m-/;s/^+/\x1b[32m+/;s/^@/\x1b[34m@/;s/$/\x1b[0m/'  looks also great

Comment: Particularly, this answer by retracile has inspired me to develop the bash function as wrapper over the original diff tool. I have briefly described it here - http://with-love-from-siberia.blogspot.ru/2016/07/color-diff.html. I have made attempt to cover all the possible formatting options. Sadly, it has some lacks described by retracile in his article but those lacks are quite rare. So I can say this it works properly.

Comment: There's always a case for doing something without involving yum, apt-get, etc. -- something as simple as not wanting to bother IT with installing yet another program that only one developer will use.

Comment: Thanks! You can also use `sed -e '1,2s/^/\x1b[97m/;3,$s/^-/\x1b[31m-/;3,$s/^+/\x1b[32m+/;3,$s/^@/\x1b[36m@/;s/$/\x1b[0m/'` for an output closer to `diff --color`.

Comment: Here is another solution that works on macOS and does not require spelling out the ANSI escape sequences explicitly: `diff -u old new | sed "s/^-/$(tput setaf 1)&/; s/^+/$(tput setaf 2)&/; s/^@/$(tput setaf 6)&/; s/$/$(tput sgr0)/"`. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/55088585/303363 for more details.

Answer (score 18):

**Coloured, *word-level* `diff` ouput**

Here's what you can do with the the below script and [diff-highlight](https://github.com/git/git/tree/master/contrib/diff-highlight):

[image: Coloured diff screenshot]

```
#!/bin/sh -eu

# Use diff-highlight to show word-level differences

diff -U3 --minimal "$@" |
  sed 's/^-/\x1b[1;31m-/;s/^+/\x1b[1;32m+/;s/^@/\x1b[1;34m@/;s/$/\x1b[0m/' |
  diff-highlight
```

<sub>(Credit to [@retracile's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16865578/5353461) for the `sed` highlighting)</sub>

Comment: How do I use this output in GVim?

Comment: For `vim`, use a plugin, eg [diffchar](https://github.com/rickhowe/diffchar.vim).

Comment: This answer deserves more credit! It uses a toolchain you probably already have, and works awesome (and applies to git log, git show, and git diff!

Comment: Actually, `diff-highlight` does not do a word-level output. It just detects a common prefix and a common suffix on a changed line. For instance, if several words are changed, it will highlight everything from the first changed word to the last changed word. Moreover, this is effective only when only one line is changed between unchanged lines. In GNU Emacs, diff-mode does much better.

Answer (score 16):

You can change the [Subversion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_Subversion) configuration to use colordiff:

**~/.subversion/config.diff**

```
 ### Set diff-cmd to the absolute path of your 'diff' program.
 ###   This will override the compile-time default, which is to use
 ###   Subversion's internal diff implementation.
-# diff-cmd = diff_program (diff, gdiff, etc.)
+diff-cmd = colordiff
```

via: https://gist.github.com/westonruter/846524

Comment: svn: Can't start process 'colordiff': Resource temporarily unavailable

Comment: Did you install colordiff?

Comment: Yup, I tried hardcoding the path as well (running in cygwin)

Comment: idk try might this http://superuser.com/questions/635995/cygwin-cant-run-process-saying-resource-temporarily-unavailable

Answer (score 11):

I use [`grc`](http://kassiopeia.juls.savba.sk/%7Egarabik/software/grc.html) (Generic Colouriser), which allows you to colour the output of a number of commands including `diff`.

It is a Python script which can be wrapped around any command. So instead of invoking `diff file1 file2`, you would invoke `grc diff file1 file2` to see colourised output. I have aliased `diff` to `grc diff` to make it easier.

Comment: Does not work on Windows with mingw/cygwin due to `fork()` calls, although likely to work with WSL.

Answer (score 10):

Since `wdiff` accepts arguments specifying the string at the beginning and end of both insertions and deletions, you can use [ANSI color sequences](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code) as those strings:

```
wdiff -n -w $'\033[30;41m' -x $'\033[0m' -y $'\033[30;42m' -z $'\033[0m' file1 file2
```

For example, this is the output of comparing two CSV files:

[image: diff output of CSV files]

Example from *[2.2 Actual examples of wdiff usage](https://www.gnu.org/software/wdiff/manual/html_node/wdiff-Examples.html)*.

Comment: `colordiff` now (1.0.16) understands `wdiff`, so you can also just pipe: `wdiff -n f1 f2 | colordiff`. `wdiff` should be merged into diffutils...

Answer (score 10):

Here is another solution that invokes `sed` to insert the appropriate ANSI escape sequences for colors to show the `+`, `-`, and `@` lines in red, green, and cyan, respectively.

```
diff -u old new | sed "s/^-/$(tput setaf 1)&/; s/^+/$(tput setaf 2)&/; s/^@/$(tput setaf 6)&/; s/$/$(tput sgr0)/"
```

Unlike the other solutions to this question, this solution does not spell out the ANSI escape sequences explicitly. Instead, it invokes the `tput setaf` and `tput sgr0` commands to generate the ANSI escape sequences to set an appropriate color and reset terminal attributes, respectively.

To see the available colors for each argument to `tput setaf`, use this command:

```
for i in {0..255}; do tput setaf $i; printf %4d $i; done; tput sgr0; echo
```

Here is how the output looks:

[image]

Here is the evidence that the `tput setaf` and `tput sgr0` commands generate the appropriate ANSI escape sequences:

```
$ tput setaf 1 | xxd -g1
00000000: 1b 5b 33 31 6d                                   .[31m
```

```
$ tput setaf 2 | xxd -g1
00000000: 1b 5b 33 32 6d                                   .[32m
```

```
$ tput setaf 6 | xxd -g1
00000000: 1b 5b 33 36 6d                                   .[36m
```

```
$ tput sgr0 | xxd -g1
00000000: 1b 28 42 1b 5b 6d                                .(B.[m
```

Comment: if you get `tput: unkown terminfo capability in  'srg0'` means your os is old and tput does not recognize srg0 , i was able to use `tput setaf 7` in last sed command to get color back to white

Answer (score 10):

No one has mentioned [delta](https://github.com/dandavison/delta) so far. It supports syntax colored diff view with **syntax highlighting**.

[image: Image source: Delta]

Comment: Wohoooo is this a terminal application?!

Comment: doesn't seem to support `.diff` files

Comment: It's in Pacman... 
`delta -s file1 file2` # -s is "side by side"

Answer (score 4):

I would suggest you to give [diff-so-fancy](https://github.com/so-fancy/diff-so-fancy) a try. I use it during my work and it sure seems great as of now. It comes packed with many options and it's really easy to configure your diffs the way you want.

You can install it by:

```
sudo npm install -g diff-so-fancy
```

or on Mac:

```
brew install diff-so-fancy
```

Afterwards, you can highlight your diffs like this:

```
diff -u file1 file2 | diff-so-fancy
```

Answer (score 4):

Character-level color diff:
Install [ccdiff](https://metacpan.org/pod/App::ccdiff)

```
ccdiff -r /usr/share/dict/words /tmp/new-dict
```

[image: Output of ccdiff]

Comment: `ccdiff` seems to work well as a diff program, but unfortunately, it cannot color an existing diff (such as a patch).

Answer (score 2):

With the [bat](https://github.com/sharkdp/bat) command:

```
diff file1 file2 | bat -l diff
```

Comment: What is *bat* supposed to do? Can you elaborate? Please respond by [editing (changing) your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/58573534/edit), not here in comments (***without*** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the answer should appear as if it was written today).

Answer (score 1):

```bash
diff --color=always file_a file_b | less
```

works for me

Answer (score 0):

On recent versions of Git on Ubuntu, you can enable diff-highlighting with:

```
sudo ln -s /usr/share/doc/git/contrib/diff-highlight/diff-highlight /usr/local/bin
sudo chmod a+x /usr/share/doc/git/contrib/diff-highlight/diff-highlight
```

And then adding this to your `.gitconfig` file:

```
[pager]
    log = diff-highlight | less
    show = diff-highlight | less
    diff = diff-highlight | less
```

It's possible the script is located somewhere else in other distributions. You can use `locate diff-highlight` to find out where.

Answer (score 0):

My favorite choice is `vdiff <file1> <file2>` function (I forgot from where I got it).

It will open two windows in [Vim](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vim_%28text_editor%29) side-by-side, to see clearly see the difference between the two files.

```sh
vdiff () {
    if [ "${#}" -ne 2 ] ; then
        echo "vdiff requires two arguments"
        echo "  comparing dirs:  vdiff dir_a dir_b"
        echo "  comparing files: vdiff file_a file_b"
        return 1
    fi

    local left="${1}"
    local right="${2}"

    if [ -d "${left}" ] && [ -d "${right}" ]; then
        vim +"DirDiff ${left} ${right}"
    else
        vim -d "${left}" "${right}"
    fi
}
```

Put this script in your (.alias) or (.zshrc), and then call it using
vdiff <file1> <file2>.

### Example

[image]

The results are:

[image]