# Traversing directories with vim file name completion in insert mode (Ctrl-X Ctrl-F)

Tags: vim, autocomplete, keyboard-shortcuts

I’m trying to use vim’s `compl-filename` feature (<kbd>Ctrl-X</kbd><kbd>Ctrl-F</kbd>) to complete paths in `INSERT` mode, but I can’t work out how to traverse into directories without (temporarily) ending the completion mode:

Let’s say I want to complete the path `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifup`.

I would like to be able to do something like:

```
/eCtrl-XCtrl-F
/etc/
/etc/sysCtrl-F
/etc/sysconfig/
/etc/sysconfig/netCtrl-F
/etc/sysconfig/netconsoleCtrl-N
/etc/sysconfig/networkCtrl-N
/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/
/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifupCtrl-Y
/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifup
```

**The issue is, as soon as I start typing* after a path match (like `/etc/`), it ends file name completion**. I would like it to stay in file name completion, so that I can still use <kbd>Ctrl-F</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl-N</kbd>, etc. Since it ends completion, I have to type <kbd>Ctrl-X</kbd><kbd>Ctrl-F</kbd> again to restart it, and the helpful completion popup menu disappears in the meantime.

Is there an option I can set to change this?

***** By ‘typing’ here, I am referring to characters in `'isfname'` -- of course, typing other characters (like space or punctuation) should not continue file name completion.

Answer (score 5):

I'm not sure exactly what you're saying, but you can just press <kbd>Ctrl-X</kbd><kbd>Ctrl-F</kbd> again on a directory while you're in the completion menu to expand it. You don't have to close out of the menu first. I just keep <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> held down and tap `xf` to traverse a directory, `n` and `p` to move up and down and `w` to go back up.

If you don't use `:h i_CTRL-F` then you could remap it. For example,

```
inoremap <C-f> <C-x><C-f>
```

Comment: If I type `^XF` immediately after completing one part of the path (ending with a `/`), I might have to scroll through many paths to find the one I want, without being able to restrict the options by typing extra characters. `^XFP` will at least let me type extra characters, but is clunky and just shouldn't be necessary.

Comment: @codebeard You shouldn't ever need to type `^XFP`. If you start typing `/et` then you can hit `^XF`. Then type `X^XF` (for example) to get to `/etc/X11/`. You can just start typing while you're in the menu without using `^P`. It's quite possible I'm biased here, but I can really imagine a better way to do it. You could `inoremap <Tab> <C-x><C-f>` if you want it to behave like bash completion.

Comment: Except that as soon as I type the 'X' here, I lose the popup menu, which is probably the goal of using file name completion in the first place -- I rarely use it to save typing (I can type a 30 character path name in less time than it takes to mess around with key combinations), but I use it when I can't remember what path I was looking for. Also, `inoremap <Tab> ...` is probably unwise given the importance of the `<Tab>` key in editing most files.

Comment: @codebeard Oops, I meant I **can't** imagine a better way to do it. There might be a plugin out there that puts you back into file completion mode until you hit `<Space>` to end it. Hope you find something that works well for you.

Answer (score 2):

Simple remap would be

```
inoremap / /<C-x><C-f>
```

So when you type slash(/) in insert mode you will get that auto completion popup :)

Place it in your .vimrc file (for vim) or in init.vim (for neovim)

Answer (score 0):

Vim doesn't do **auto**-completion.

For that, you'll need a dedicated plugin like [AutoComplPop](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1879) or [NeoComplCache](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2620)

Answer (score 0):

Please use insert "i" first before using cntr+x+f. I was in similar situation. :)

Comment: ? didnt help here. You mean to be in insert-mode?