# Is there a way to color highlight difference while using sdiff?

Tags: linux, unix, sed, diff, sdiff

I'm comparing two files using sdiff to get side by side difference but I want the difference to be color highlighted.
Ex:
File A:
Hello There! General Kenobi!
Magic

File B:
Hello World! Hola
Magic

Now the output from sdiff will be:
Hello There! General Kenobi! | Hello World! Hola

I want the diff highlighted like (couldn't color code so, bold and italics)
Hello **There**! **General Kenobi!** | Hello *World*! *Hola*

I can't use GUI based or colordiff command etc.
I tried using sed and last option is to pipe the sdiff output through a script, but I'm thinking there might be a better way.

Comment: this might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8800578/how-to-colorize-diff-on-the-command-line

Comment: I've already gone through that and it wasn't much helpful as I can't use many of the mentioned commands and even --color option of diff.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to colorize diff on the command line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8800578/how-to-colorize-diff-on-the-command-line)

Answer (score 0):

[csdiff](https://github.com/prioux/csdiff) is a small wrapper script to colorize the output of `sdiff`.

It works well for colorizing the side-by-side diff, but it doesn't work with `sdiff`'s interactive mode (`-o`).

You can also just use `diff --color=always --side-by-side` for similar results, or [icdiff](https://github.com/jeffkaufman/icdiff).

Answer (score -1):

The emacs command `ediff-buffers` produces colourised output. But you have to be using emacs :-)