# How can I visualize per-character differences in Git Gui staged changes view?

Tags: git, git-gui, gitk

Currently it only shows the lines that are different. Is there any way to make it visualize per-character difference inside those lines, same way as it does in Github here or in gitk in "color words" mode? https://github.com/microsoft/dotnet/pull/1282/files/cadcf3de421c9eabc1eb2f538bf26d9be3c65a91

UPD this question is NOT about gitk, read the title

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgitk%5D+word+diff

Comment: As I understand, `git gui` just launches `gittk`. @phd However, this question should still be reopened. The linked answer explains only how to show **word** differences, which are extremely verbose and much harder to read than **character** differences, which are asked for here. The linked answer is equivalent to `--color-words`; This question wants `--color-words=.`.

Answer (score 0):

This is the best answer I've found (in fact I'm turning it on now for myself!)
https://stackoverflow.com/a/58405511/1007707

It is only for command line (I checked it doesn't affect git-gui), so probably not as helpful for git-gui.

Basically follow the instructions that come with recent GIT packages, on my system in /usr/share/doc/git/contrib/diff-highlight/README

Also, git-gui is a little dated, you may want to try another tool like git-cola or similar?

Comment: does it have this feature?

Comment: Unfortunately no, but git cola at least supports you launching a 3rd party diff-tool which (right click select Lauch Diff Tool) *does* have intraline support. Maybe like DiffMerge.